# Script won't split line at "=" Delimeter

Tags: vbscript

The script below works in finding duplicates.

But most of the files i'm reading follow this format:

```
ServerName(1) = "Example1"
ServerName(2) = "Example1"
ServerName(3) = "Example3"
ServerName(4) = "Example4"
ServerName(5) = "Example5"
```

The 'cut' variable in the code below is supposed to cut the string at the `"="` delimiter and return the value that comes after the `"="` delimeter. 
It should write to the duplicate file `"Example1"` but instead writes nothing. How would I make it so that the script below reads a file and only finds the duplicate in values after the `"="` delimeter.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



FileName = "Test.txt"
PathToSave = "C:"



Path = (PathToSave &  FileName)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Path, ForReading)
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(PathToSave & "Noduplicates.txt", 2, True)
Set objOutputFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(PathToSave & "Duplicates.txt", 2, True)

objOutputFile.WriteLine ("This document contains the " & path & " file without duplicates" & vbcrlf)
objOutputFile2.WriteLine ("This document contains the duplicates found. Each line listed below had a duplicate in " & Path & vbcrlf)
Dim DuplicateCount
DuplicateCount = 0
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do until objFile.atEndOfStream
    strCurrentLine = LCase(Trim(objFile.ReadLine))
    Cut = Split(strCurrentline,"=")

    If not Dict.Exists(LCase(Trim(cut(strCurrentLine)))) then 
        objOutputFile.WriteLine strCurrentLine
        Dict.Add strCurrentLine,strCurrentLine
    Else Dict.Exists(LCase(Trim(cut(strCurrentLine))))
        objOutputFile2.WriteLine strCurrentLine
        DuplicateCount = DuplicateCount + 1
    End if 
Loop

If DuplicateCount > 0 then
    wscript.echo ("Number of Duplicates Found: " & DuplicateCount)
Else 
    wscript.echo "No Duplicates found"
End if
```

Comment: One thing I see is that you never use the `Cut` array after the line `Cut = Split(strCurrentline,"=",1)`.

Comment: I was and I Edited it to show what I had before. But before I was receiving the `type mismatch 'cut'` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cut` is your array, so `Cut(1)` is the portion after the `=`. So that's what you should test for in your dictionary.

```
If InStr(strCurrentline, "=") > 0 Then

    Cut = Split(strCurrentline,"=")

    If Not Dict.Exists(Cut(1)) then 
        objOutputFile.WriteLine strCurrentLine
        Dict.Add Cut(1), Cut(1)
    Else
        objOutputFile2.WriteLine strCurrentLine
        DuplicateCount = DuplicateCount + 1
    End if 

End If
```

Comment: When I use this method it throws the error `subscript out of range: '[number: 1]'`.

Comment: Make sure every line contains a `=` before you attempt to split it. Use a check like `If InStr(strCurrentline, "=") > 0 Then` before calling the `Split()` function. I've updated it to include this test.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help.

Answer (score -2):

I makes no sense at all to ask [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to return an array with **one** element by setting the 3rd parameter to 1, as in

```
Cut = Split(strCurrentline,"=",1)
```

Evidence:

```
>> WScript.Echo Join(Split("a=b", "=", 1), "*")
>>
a=b
>> WScript.Echo Join(Split("a=b", "="), "*")
>>
a*b
```

BTW: `ServerName(5) = "Example5"` should be splitted on " = "; further thought about the quotes may be advisable.

**Update wrt comments (and downvotes):**

The semantics of the count parameter according to the docs:

> count
>
> ```
> Optional. Number of substrings to be returned; -1 indicates that all substrings are returned. If omitted, all substrings are returned.
> ```

Asking for one element (not an UBound!) results in one element containing the input.

Evidence wrt the type mismatch error:

```
>> cut = Split("a=b", "=", 1)
>> WScript.Echo cut
>>
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
>>
```

So please think twice.

Comment: So...how is this an answer?

Comment: The 1 was there to make sure that only the values after `=` would be compared for duplicates.

Comment: With the number 1 removed it still returns the Type Mismatch error

Comment: @roryap - it answers the question "why does my Split on "=" fail?" by pointing out that Split will *never* work as expected when you set the 3rd/count parameter to 1. Abdullahi's later comment shows that reading the docs on Split carefully would be of help.